# MVC5 entity Framework database first with string primary key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, frameworks, entity

I created a database first entity framework MVC5 application. The table has a string primary key.I used scaffolding to create the controller. My controller/Index works fine but Details, Edit and Create doesn't work. If i use int primary key all CRUD works fine.
Does EF not support the string primary keys.

Here is my Index.cshtml

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Owner)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Property_Ref }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Property_Ref }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Property_Ref })
    </td>

</tr>
}
```

This is my Controller

```
 // GET: /Property/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Tables.ToList());
    }

    // GET: /Property/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Table table = db.Tables.Find(id);
        if (table == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(table);
    }

    // GET: /Property/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

All this code is generated by MVC5 Database first and using scaffolding for controller.

The Index works fine and list all records, 
When I click Details, I get an error **Server Error in '/' Application.**

`http://localhost:51356/Property/Details/2` - here 2 is a string primary key![enter image description here][1]

Many thanks

Comment: Can you add a more detailed exception? This doesn't tells us anything.

Comment: Did you set "Property_Ref" as primary key in database?

Answer (score 1):

As Jhoon Bey said, make sure that the table has 'Property_Ref' marked as Primary key before you build the EF data model from your database. FYR, the working code:

**Table:**

[image: Table]

**EF Model:**

[image: EF Model]

**Controller:**

```
private TestDbEntities1 db = new TestDbEntities1();

    // GET: /Person/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.People.ToList());
    }

    // GET: /Person/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Person person = db.People.Find(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(person);
    }

    // GET: /Person/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Index:**

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Property_ref }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Property_ref }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Property_ref })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}